# Is Fortigate-60D a fanless model?

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

I would like to know if Fortigate-60D is a fanless model or not. However, neither [Fortigate-60D datasheet](http://www.fortinet.com/sites/default/files/productdatasheets/FortiGate-60D.pdf) nor [Fortinet Product Matrix](http://www.fortinet.com/sites/default/files/basicfiles/ProductMatrix.pdf) provide any information about this topic.

Could you please confirm, either by your own experience or referencing any other document?

Comment: it's rather small to have a bank of fans in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product datasheet for the Fortigate-60 specs out the **Heat Dissipation** at **40BTU/h** and **Operating Temperature** at a max of **104F**. This is typical for a fanless design. See [these small HP office switches](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/networking/products/switches/HP_1405_Small_Office_Switch_Series/index.aspx#J9792A) with similar power rating showing **Fanless** designation.

Comment: I have both a 60C and a 60DWifi on my desk right now and both appear to be fanless. Unless there's something unusual about the 60D, the above answer should be correct.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Fortigate FG-60D and it's sibling FortiWifi FWF-60D are both fanless. I've seen and sold a lot of them.